# Redux: Reducer overwrites previous state on new add

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to implement a simple shopping cart functionality using Redux and pure Javascript. I've split my reducers in two, one for UI and one for the cart-functionality.

My problem is, when adding an item to the cart, it shows up fine in state, but when I add another item, it overwrites the previous item in state. I've struggled with this for a while, and tried multiple solutions.

```
const initialState = {
  visibilityFilter: VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL,
  shop: {
    purchasedItems: [],
    shopItems: [...shop.items]
  }
}

function shopReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
      case BUY_ITEM:
      const clickedItem = state.shopItems.filter( item => item.id == action.id);
      return {...state, purchasedItems: [...state.purchasedItems, clickedItem ] }

function buyItemShop(id) {
  return {
    type: BUY_ITEM,
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Always Keep in mind the word "Immutable".

Answer (score 1):

*Object destructuring* does not perform a *deep merge*.

Anyways, you have some other issues because you are not using the proper keys from the state.

Should be instead:

```
  return {
    ...state,
    shop: {
      purchasedItems: [...state.shop.purchasedItems, clickedItem],
      shopItems: state.shop.shopItems,
    },
  }
```

Comment: As my shopReducer only handles the shop-slice of my initial state, this will set up a new shop key on the same level as PurchasedItems and shopItems.

State in this reducers scope is only PurchasedItems and shopItems, so a shallow mere should suffice, as I understand it (as I said, the first addition shows up fine in purchasedItems array, the problem is the second addition overwrites the first.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, tbh.

Comment: console.log(state) from within the reducer

{purchasedItems: Array(0), shopItems: Array(4)}
purchasedItems: []
shopItems: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 0):

This works - simply needed to spread the clickedItem object in the return statement.

```
function shopReducer(state = initialState.shop, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case BUY_ITEM:
      let clickedItem = state.shopItems.filter( item => item.id == action.id);
      return {...state, cartItems: [...state.cartItems, ...clickedItem ] }
```